# Pulp Elastic Constraint Variable Penalty Value

Tags: pulp, linear-optimization

In PuLP one may declare a constraint as elastic and add a penalty (https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/pulp.html?highlight=lpsum#elastic-constraints).

Let’s say i have the elastic constraint `C(x) = 200`. May I specify a penalty that increases the further `C(X)` is away from 200 or may the penalty be only a fixed value?

In other words, may the penalty include decision variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Penalty Function For Linear Optimization PuLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77315236/penalty-function-for-linear-optimization-pulp)