# Penalty Function For Linear Optimization PuLP

Tags: pulp, linear-optimization

Let's say I have 2 decision variables `a`, `b` and 2 constants `constant_a`, `constant_b`. I want to maximize `a` and `b` but add a penalty whenever `a` is superior to `constant_a` or `b` is superior to `constant_b`.

The penalty should be `-0.05 * (a - constant_a)` (and an equal setup for `b`).

How may i implement this in PuLP? Note that this is a simplified version of my actual linear optimization problem.

I tried [elastic constraints](https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/pulp.html?highlight=lpsum#elastic-constraints) but this way I may only specifiy a fixed penalty value (and not `-0.05 * (decision variable - constant)`).

Comment: As it stands, with a coefficient of 0.05, the problem is unbounded. The penalties will never "catch up" with the growth of `a` and `b`, so the latter will grow indefinitely.

Comment: In fact, for _any_ coefficient below 1, the penalty will have no effect and the problem will be unbounded. For any coefficient above 1, the penalty will turn into a de-facto bound of `constant_a`.

Comment: This is an extremely simplified version. In reality there exist multiple `a` and `b` variables that are constrained properly.
Let's say the optimal solution for my problem is found with `a = 5` and `b = 2` (without my penalty). The constants are both equal to `3`. Now i would like to implement the penalty in the optimization so that `a` were to be punished and thus maybe selected differently as `a > 3` while `b` would be rewarded as `b  < 3` and thus maybe selected differently. The overall aim is the maximization of the variables but they should be selected so that the penalty is minimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the immediate question of how to construct such a penalty, but in context I will maintain that it still probably doesn't accomplish what OP imagines it will.

```py
import pulp

constant_a = 3
constant_b = 3
a = pulp.LpVariable(name='a', upBound=5, cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
b = pulp.LpVariable(name='b', upBound=5, cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
a_penalty = pulp.LpVariable(name='a_penalty', lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
b_penalty = pulp.LpVariable(name='b_penalty', lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpContinuous)

prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='penalty', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
prob.objective = a_penalty + b_penalty - a - b
prob.addConstraint(name='a_pty_lower', constraint=a_penalty >= 0.05*(a - constant_a))
prob.addConstraint(name='b_pty_lower', constraint=b_penalty >= 0.05*(b - constant_b))
prob.addConstraint(name='fake', constraint=a + b == 7)

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal
print(f'a={a.value()}  a_penalty={a_penalty.value()}')
print(f'b={b.value()}  b_penalty={b_penalty.value()}')
```

```
a=4.0  a_penalty=0.05
b=3.0  b_penalty=0.0
```

The penalty variables have a lower bound of 0 (taken when the associated variables are below the penalty limit), no upper bound, and a constraint that they have a lower limit of the penalty value when subtracted from the constraint limit.

Comment: I do not want the penalty values, but want the penalty values to affect the decision variables. Let's say `a` and `b` may be bound to values in between `0` and `1`. My constraint is `a + b <= 1`. This may yield many solutions (for ex. `a = 1 and b = 0`, `a = 0.5 and b = 0.5`, ...). Let's say my constants are `constant_a = 0` and `constant_b = 1`. This way the optimization should punish any values of `a > 0` and `b > 1`. This way the optimization yields `a = 0` and `b = 1`. Note that I do not want `a > 0` and `b > 1` to be fixed constraints (as this makes my real world optimization infesable).

Comment: I think there's some fundamental misunderstanding here about the way that linear programming works. This _does_ affect the way that `a` and `b` are optimized, because there's a single objective function, and that objective function now carries penalties that are based on `a` and `b`. This solution answers the immediate question. My crystal ball is malfunctioning today so I can't speak to how it affects your higher-complexity problem construction unless you show it.

Comment: Maximize: `a + b + 0.05 * (constant_a - a) + 0.05 * (constant_b - b)`. Kind of like this but this would not work as one can not specify constants in the objective function.

Comment: _one can not specify constants in the objective function_ is untrue, but anyway: have you read the code? That's what this does.

Comment: You may add constants, but they won't affect the decision variables. I think your code may do what I try to achieve. I will try to implement this. Thanks for your answers. I did not paste the whole problem as it includes more than 150.000 variables and thus would be a lot to read.

Comment: I did successfully implement this. Thank you.